# Running a Python Script from Google Storage Bucket in terminal

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hello I am trying to run a python code in my google storage bucket through a terminal, but I have no clue what I am doing right now.

I connected ssh to my VM like below:
[image: screenshot of my terminal]

To run `create_pretraining_data.py` code which is located under the `bert` folder, I've tried

```
python3 create_pretraining_data.py --input_file ...

python3 gs://bucket-hosrevbert-1/bert/create_pretraining_data.py --input_file ...
```

but those all return `No such file or directory`

I think I'm just missing one simple point, but I am not sure what would be.

Can you guys please give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not possible to run a python script that is in a bucket. You need to at least save it on locally, then run the script. You can copy the file using `gsutil cp gs://your-bucket/file.txt /your/local/directory/file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse) for that. Mount your bucket in a directory

```
gcsfuse bucket-hosrevbert-1 /path/to/mount/
```

And then run your script

```
python3 /path/to/mount/bert/create_pretraining_data.py --....
```